# why the generator generates 4 elements but not 6

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

```
from collections import deque 
def moving_average(iterable, n=3):
# moving_average([40, 30, 50, 46, 39, 44]) --> 40.0 42.0 45.0 43.0
    it = iter(iterable)
    d = deque(itertools.islice(it, n-1))
    d.appendleft(0)
    s = sum(d)
    for elem in it:
        s += elem - d.popleft()
        d.append(elem)
        yield s / float(n)

a = [40, 30, 50, 46, 39, 44]
list(moving_average(a))
```

Why the function moving_average generates 4 elements `[40.0,42.0,45.0,43.0]` but not 6 elements that are `[36.66666667,33.33333333,40.0,42.0,45.0,43.0]`

I expected the code to do this:

- first, d is `deque([40,30])`, then `d.appendleft(0)` make `deque([0,40,30])`, so `s` is 70
- in the `for` loop, the first elem is `40`, so then `s = s + elem - d.popleft()` is `s = 70 + 40 - 0 = 110`
- then `d.append(elem)` is `deque([40,30,40])` and `s/float(3)=110/3.0=36.66666667`

and so on.

Comment: So what values, when summed and divided by 3, produce 36.66666667 and 33.33333333?

Comment: first, d is deque([40,30]),then d.appendleft(0) is deque([0,40,30]), s is 70, in th for loop, the first elem is 40, then s = s + elem - d.popleft() is s = 70 + 40 - 0 = 110, then d.append(elem) is deque([40,30,40]), s/float(3)=110/3.0=36.66666667. and so on

Comment: No, the first `elem` is `50`, not `40`. `40` and `30` where removed from the input iterable. `itertools.islice()` *iterated over `it`*.

Comment: So you get `s = 70 + 50 - 0 = 120`, and `d.append(elem)` produces `deque([40, 30, 50])`. The next `elem` is `46`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 4 triplets in the input to calculate the average for:

1. 40, 30, 50  == 40.0
2. 30, 50, 46  == 42.0
3. 50, 46, 39  == 45.0
4. 46, 39, 44  == 43.0

When you leave `n` to the default, it will only generate an average for every 3 values, and won't produce an average for a partial window.

There is *no combination of 3 of those numbers* that would ever produce your expected output:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [c for c in combinations(a, 3) if sum(c) in (100, 110)]  # average 36 1/3rd and 33 1/3rd
[]
```

You appear to have missed that `itertools.islice(it, n-1)` removed the first two elements from the `iter(iterable)` iterator. Those first two elements `40` and `30` are not part of the `for elem in it:` for loop and the *first `elem` value is `50`*.

Comment: but the function actually generate a rolling window, but I don't know  why

Comment: @littlely: because it uses a queue? It stores the first 2 elements and 0 into the queue, creates a sum. Then in a loop, the next value (3rd) is added to the sum, the first value in the queue subtracted (starting with `0`, but will be `40` in the next step, etc) to keep the sum for the 3 values up-to-date. The queue only ever holds 3 elements.